# How to test that a javascript method creates an object and calls a method on that object

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I'm updating server code written in nodejs and trying to add unit test as i go and i can't find a good solution for the following case:

```
classX.prototype.methodX = function () {
    // Create new session
    var session = new classY();

    // Add the new session to the global list
    self.sessions[session.sessionId] = session;

    session.sendPushNotificationToCallee(); }
```

I can easily test that the session object was added to the list of session, but how can i check that the sendPushNotificationToCallee was actually called? My original intent was to use sinon.js spies, but i can't find a way to do that as the object is created in the method...

Thanks

Comment: Don't call `new` inside `methodX` - instead either pass a factory to the constructor or use dependency injection (pass the session as a parameter). Objects creating things that they're dependent on is a sure-fire way to make code that's hard to test. If you passed a factory in or got it via DI you could have easily mocked everything you want. It would also been explicit to the outside.

Comment: Of course since this is JS you can also just do `classY = function(){ return {sendPushNotificationToCallee: /* your hook here */ }`, but for the general case you want dependencies to be explicit. Why test `sendPushNotificationToCallee` if it is not exposed to the outside that this happens?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, methodX is called after a web socket sends an event, so i don't think i can pass the dependency as the web socket will not know to create the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward if your code meets following assumptions:

1. `classY` is a standard JS constructor, ie. its methods are defined on its prototype. This means you can attach your sinon spy there.
2. `classX` and `classY` are located in a separate modules. Because node's `require` is a singleton, this means you can `require('classY')` in your test and you will get exactly the same object as in `classX` module.

Then a simple test will look like this:

```
var classX = require('./classX'); // module under test
var classY = require('./classY'); 

var sinon = require('sinon');
var assert = require('assert');

// spy on a method
var spy = sinon.spy(classY.prototype, 'sendPushNotificationToCallee');

// instantiate the class and call the method under test
var instance = classX();
instance.methodX();

// test
assert.ok(spy.calledOnce);

// restore orignal method
classY.prototype.sendPushNotificationToCallee.restore();
```